# Listening to changes in the Text property of the WPF TextBlock control

Tags: wpf, event-handling, ellipsis

For a WPF TextBlock, setting the TextTrimming to TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis will cause it to automatically cut off the text before it overflows and add some ellipses to the end. [This article](http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/) shows how to check if the text is being trimmed and automatically show the full text in a tooltip when it is.

It does this, without subclassing TextBlock, by registering an event handler that listens to the SizeChanged event:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
    typeof( TextBlock ),
    FrameworkElement.SizeChangedEvent,
    new SizeChangedEventHandler( OnTextBlockSizeChanged ),
    true );
```

The trouble is, this only reacts to size changed events - it works fine if the text overflows because you shrank the control, but not if it overflows because you changed the text.

Unfortunately, although the TextBlock does have a SizeChangedEvent, it doesn't have a TextChangedEvent. I thought of listening to the TargetUpdated event:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
    typeof(TextBlock),
    Binding.TargetUpdatedEvent,
    new EventHandler<DataTransferEventArgs>(OnTextBlockTextChanged),
    true);
```

But that didn't have any discernable effect, even with the NotifyOnTargetUpdated property set to true. I also tried overriding the metadata on the TextProperty but it seems that can really only be done in its static constructor - in this case the TextBlock's static constructor. Is there any way of achieving this without subclassing TextBlock?

Comment: You can override metadata property for any property on any type. Create a static class of your own and call `TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata` from your class static constructor. All you'll have to do is make sure that this constructor gets called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx):

```
var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
descriptor.AddValueChanged(...);
```

PS. Why on Earth `TextBlock` does not have an `IsTrimmed` property is beyond me.

Comment: Thank you Kent! I spent an hour trying to figure this out!

Comment: This requires to be manually called on *each* concerned `TextBlock` element, *and* it must also be removed to prevent memory leaks. IMHO this isn't the right approach.